# How to validate input, in non-form element, on keyup with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have a site that is being built in ASPX. Unfortunately, because of this fact, I cannot actually use the `<form>` tag to wrap my inputs, and as far as I can see, [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) only supports validating inputs within a `<form>`. Is there any way to validate these inputs, using the specified rules, on `keyup` without having them wrapped in a `<form>` tag?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form-container').validate({
    rules: {
      useremail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      userstate: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 2
      }
    },
    messages: {
      useremail: 'Please enter a valid email',
      userstate: 'Please enter your state',
    }
  });
  
  $('.form-container input').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).validate();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-container">
  <input type="text" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="text" name="userstate" placeholder="State" maxlength="2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't the `<form>` tag work?

Comment: Because the entire site is wrapped in a `form` tag, so using the `form` tag would create nested forms. It's a restriction from the client that I cannot use it.

Comment: Nested forms is also invalid HTML.

Comment: So, attach it to the existing `<form>` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have nested forms, which is invalid HTML, and you must attach `.validate()` to a `form` container.  There are no workarounds.

You're also using `.validate()` all wrong.  Since this is the primary initialization method of the plugin, wrapping it within a `keyup` handler is not correct.  Plus the plugin already uses the `keyup` event to trigger validation.

And no, you cannot put form input elements within a `div` and then target that `div` attached to `.validate()`.  It will be ignored.  You can only target `form` elements attached to `.validate()`.

Furthermore, since you're using ASP, you can leverage its built-in Unobtrusive Validation plugin, which automatically constructs and calls the `.validate()` method based upon your data attributes.  Just remember that if you follow this route, you cannot call `.validate()` yourself.  The plugin only allows one call, and once initialized, all subsequent calls to `.validate()` are ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is it possible to use the jQuery validation plugin in the way I described? Unfortunately I don't actually have access to the solution myself(I will be handing off files) so I can't leverage the built-in plugin.

Comment: @user13286, No.  You cannot have nested forms and you must attach `.validate()` to a `form`.  There are no workarounds.  Editing my answer with such, but I thought I already explained that clearly enough: *"you cannot put form input elements within a `div` and then target that `div` attached to `.validate()`. It will be ignored. You can only target `form` elements attached to `.validate()`."*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I appreciate it.